# Can't add a <fo : inline > element to my xsl

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

At my work iv got a small bug. Just need to underline a small text part. 
But im getting an error when trying to add a  tag. 
Its giving me the error report that its not a valid child.

The error is as follows:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:inline" is not a valid child of "fo:flow"! (See fo:flow, "Mademoiselle ADS S, 1, 10000 TRO...")
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2304)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:682)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2336)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:393)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:247)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2336)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:682)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2336)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:682)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2336)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:682)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2336)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.applyTemplateToNode(TransformerImpl.java:2202)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transformNode(TransformerImpl.java:1276)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:673)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1192)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1170)
    at com.albiran.ebiza.utilitaires.PDFGenerator.produceXMLData(PDFGenerator.java:117)
    at com.satec.pdf.SAPDFGenerator.generatePDF(SAPDFGenerator.java:163)
    at com.albiran.ebiza.envoi.AsyncAttachment.getPath(AsyncAttachment.java:41)
    ... 3 more
```

And the xsl file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:import href="SAPdfUtils.xsl" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <!-- ******************************** Déclaration, des pages ************************** -->
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="mainpage"
                    page-width="21cm" page-height="29.7cm" margin-top="1cm"
                    margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm">
                    <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body"
                        extent="0cm" margin-top="5cm" margin-bottom="2.5cm" margin-left="2cm"
                        margin-right="2cm" />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="mainpage"
                font-family="Arial">

                <!-- ******************************** Body ************************** -->
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-size="12pt"
                    font-family="Arial" text-align="justify">

                    <!-- Page 1 -->
                    <xsl:call-template name="break" />
                    <xsl:call-template name="page1" />
                    <fo:block break-after="page" />

                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="page1">
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
            <fo:table-column column-width="60%" />
            <fo:table-column column-width="40%" />
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row text-align="left" font-weight="bold">
                    <xsl:call-template name="cellBreak" />
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="/document/contractor/nameLong" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <xsl:call-template name="break" />
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="/document/contractor/road" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <xsl:call-template name="break" />
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="/document/contractor/city" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />
        <fo:block text-align="right">
            Paris, le
            <xsl:value-of select="/document/date" />
        </fo:block>
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />

        <fo:block font-weight="bold">
            Votre référence client : N°
            <xsl:value-of select="/document/contractor/id" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-weight="bold">
            N° de contrat :
            <xsl:value-of select="/document/policy/id" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-weight="bold">
            Intitulé du produit :
            <xsl:value-of select="/document/policy/productName" />
        </fo:block>
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />


            <fo:inline text-decoration="underline">
            Objet : Remise en vigueur de votre contrat d’assurance.
            </fo:inline>

        <fo:block padding="-10px">
            <fo:leader leader-length="90%" leader-pattern="rule"
                rule-style="solid" rule-thickness="0.1mm" color="black" />
        </fo:block>
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />

        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="/document/contractor/longTitle" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </fo:block>
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />

        <fo:block>
            Suite à votre règlement du 
            <xsl:value-of select="/document/dateOfThePayment" />
            de votre prime de
            <xsl:value-of select="/document/unpaidAmount" />
            <xsl:call-template name="space" />
            <xsl:text>€</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="space" />
            pour la période du
            <xsl:value-of select="/document/startDate" />
            au
            <xsl:value-of select="/document/endDate" />
            , nous vous confirmons la remise en vigueur votre contrat d’assurance en date d’effet du 
            <xsl:value-of select="/document/reinstatementDate" />
            .
        </fo:block>
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />

        <fo:block>
            Nous restons à votre disposition. 
        </fo:block>
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />




        <fo:block>
            Nous vous prions de croire,
            <xsl:value-of select="/document/contractor/longTitle" />
            <xsl:text>, en l'expression de nos sentiments dévoués.</xsl:text>
        </fo:block>
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />
        <xsl:call-template name="break" />

        <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
            <fo:table-column column-width="60%" />
            <fo:table-column column-width="40%" />
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <xsl:call-template name="cellBreak" />
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            Votre Conseiller SATEC
                        </fo:block>
                        <xsl:call-template name="break" />
                        <fo:block>
                            Tél. : 
                            <xsl:value-of select="/document/satecPhone" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="cellBreak">
        <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:call-template name="break" />
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tableLineBreak">
        <fo:table-row>
            <xsl:call-template name="cellBreak" />
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't really have to much experience with xsl files sadly. And iv seen that people had this problem but for different reasons.

Thank you in advance and sorry if im missing something simple or trivial, im just not sure as to what may be the problem here.

Comment: I would have thought that already fo:table or fo:block should not be children of fo:flow. I usually wrap everything under the fo:flow in `fo:block-container/fo:block` but that might be some kind of fiddeling until you have it looking like before.

Comment: Unless I am misreading something, I see no template in your XSL named "break" yet you call it all the time.

Comment: Ye....I found the problem. The fo:block under the text i want underline is the line thats the problem right now. It was right under and i was blind. But thank you for the useful information. That helped A LOT too. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fo:inline` should be inside an `fo:block` or similar.

If you look at the definition of `fo:flow` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_flow), you'll see that its content model is `(%block;)+`.  If you follow the link from `%block;` to its definition, you'll see that the block-level FOs are:

- block
- block-container
- table-and-caption
- table
- list-block

You can also use `fo:float` or any of the 'neutral containers' as a child of `fo:flow`.

Of all of these, only `fo:block` can directly contain an `fo:inline`.

If you use the oXygen XML editor, you can use **focheck** (https://github.com/AntennaHouse/focheck) to validate your FO file before submitting it to your FO processor.

Comment: I did put it in a <fo:block> to start with but what happens is that the block gets underlined and the inline also. And iv got no clue why. Before that the block had a property for underlining. But the line went till the end of the page. I only need the text underlined. So i removed that and added it to the fo:inline.

Comment: Even if i remove every attribute, from the block and the inline. The block is still underlined......